# Activate Firebase App Check Debug Provider in React Native iOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-app-check

From the docs:

I have to add this to the `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
FIRAppCheckDebugProviderFactory *providerFactory =
      [[FIRAppCheckDebugProviderFactory alloc] init];
[FIRAppCheck setAppCheckProviderFactory:providerFactory];

// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
[FIRApp configure];
```

Managed to do this and to start my react native app.

However:

`Launch the app. A local debug token will be logged when the SDK tries to send a request to the backend. For example:`

I have no way of accessing the logs produced by the simulator.
In the Terminal window I can only see logs generated by React Native, and when opening the System Log in the iOS simulator this is all I get:

```
Jul 30 12:11:56 **** syslogd[55934]: --- syslogd restarted ---
Jul 30 12:11:56 **** syslogd[55934]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsAutocomplete" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

I can't run the project from inside Xcode as I get build errors on some of the postbuild steps. I run it using `yarn ios` which maps to `react-native run-ios` in `package.json`

How do I access the printed debug token in order to get App Check working when running my app in a simulator? How do I get the logs the iOS simulator is generating as we normally see in Xcode when running a native app?

Note: I have a lot of experience with native iOS development and with JS development, but this is my first time working on a React Native app (external codebase I am supposed to do some maintenance on).

Comment: did you ever find a solution here? currently dealing with the same thing.

Comment: Nope. Had to give up on it. TBH I absolutely hate all these cross-platform development environments. You just swap one set of problems for another and in the end it's not always cheaper. Especially for long term projects that require maintenance for 5+ years.

Comment: We got it around by just checking if the device was a simulator, and if it was, passing a custom environment value to bypass app check